# A mysterious letter in the mail

Tags: logical-deduction, word

## The other day I got a letter in the mail....

It was a weird one, one that obviously boasts a puzzle.

### The Letter

It states the following

> I like pigs, don't you? Won't you come and see the piggies with me. I always wanted to do this fun trip. The farm is where we go!
> I ***love love love love love love love*** pigs don't you too! You and me, together, like uz, will go to the town of fun. Mr will run!

### The letter came with a safe, I don't feel like breaking it open through the spirit of the puzzle.

The safe has 11 letter slots, but the letters can be empty.

So it can be from 1-11 letter word.

## IMPORTANT

I use https://justpaste.it for this, any letters and numbers will be like: https://justpaste.it/lettersandnumbers...

### HINT

> Notice the mistakes and the love word.....

**GOOD LUCK!**

<sub>This puzzle is easy, mostly because I am lazy. If you like this type of puzzle, I will make a harder one next time.</sub>

Comment: Your second link gives a 404

Comment: What is it called?

Comment: @DanielS notice the q is lowercase... hint hint

Comment: **HINT HINT**
Lastly, Caesar was a good ruler because he was very cipher....

Comment: Caesar, like, the Caesar Cipher? Is this leading to rot13?
EDIT: btw there is not a single _q_ in the whole puzzle. What q are you referring to?

Comment: It's in the second part, (not the letter). And yes, there is ONLY a Caesar Cipher. (no rot13). Also, I might just give the solution out, as people are stumped on this.